# How can I write conditional logic with the returned value from mongoose db.collection.find()?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Good evening Stack Overflow,

I am working on a personal project and I am trying to figure out why I am not able to get the correct response from my backend API. Below you will find code from one of the routes that I am writing. Here I am trying to get a Persona from the database by its arcana field.

My thought process is that if the mongoose method find() fails to find personas with the given arcana then I should return a 404 error and send back a json response detailing what went wrong.

I thought I would be able to do this by saying if(!personas) where personas is what is returned by the mongoose db.collection.find(). This is not working and my API returns empty square brackets with a 200 OK status. All of my testing is being done through Postman.

The console.logs in the code are my debug statements.

console.log(personas === {} ? true : false); Returns false

console.log(typeof personas); Returns object

console.log(personas === [] ? true : false); Returns false

console.log(personas === undefined ? true : false); Returns false

```
router.get("/personas/by/:arcana", (req, res) => {
const errors = {};
// The below logic is not working. We're not sending a 404 on failure.
Persona.find({ arcana: req.params.arcana })
.then(personas => {
  console.log(personas === {} ? true : false);
  console.log("What is the type of the personas variable?",typeof personas);
  console.log(personas === [] ? true : false);
  if (!personas) {
    errors.no_personas =
      "There are no personas in the compendium with that arcana.";
    return res.status(404).json(errors);
  }
  res.json(personas);
})
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ personas: "There are no personas." }));
});
```

How can I write my logic so that the correct status code is returned from the backend?

Comment: You can't equate 2 objects or arrays using '==='. You would only ever get true if you compared 2 variables that pointed to the same object: `const obj1 = {test: '1'}; const obj2 = obj1;` obj1 === obj2 returns true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!personas.length)` or `if (personas.length === 0)`. If `personas` is an empty array or object, it is not falsey.